# Draw routes in Leaflet and Wax

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm using Leaflet and MapBox. I need to develop an api which will show certain city points with labels, and accordingly draw routes between them. I have BlueMarble tiles till certain zoom, and then MapBox Streets. What is the best way to realize that idea? Are circles and paths the best option? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that you need to create an API for what you want to do.

http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/examples/geojson.html

In the Leaflet tutorials it shows you how to create LineStrings and Points from GeoJson data. So with latitude and longitude coordinates for the Cities you can create Points and use LineStrings to create the routes and add a them as a GeoJson Layer to the map.